# Photoshop Script Resize Image, does not update the resolution

Tags: graphics, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have an image when manually resized to width 1000pts the resolution comes to 261.5pixels/inch

**Original Image Dimensions**

[image]

***Manual Update  width to 1000pts***

[image]

The resolution downgraded to 261.5 px/in

When i try the same programmatically with js script the width changes but resolution is same as of the original image

**JS Code**

```
 document.resizeImage(UnitValue(parseInt(row.width),"pt"), null, null); //working
```

where row.width = 1000

**Image dimensions after executing the js script**

[image]

How to calculate the resolution of the image automatically and set to 261.5px/inch

Comment: I think you need to use `resizeCanvas` and not `resizeImage` for this

Comment: Tried resizeCanvas, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new resolution should be manually calculated.

```
newResolution = document.resolution * (originalWidth / parseInt(row.width));
document.resizeImage(null, null, newResolution, ResampleMethod.NONE);
document.resizeImage(UnitValue(parseInt(row.width), "pt"), null, null);
```

If the width is changed, the height will be changed programatically, which caused an impression, ResampleMethod.NONE will set the resolution too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to shrink the image or the canvas. I've got with the former.

Use `app.activeDocument.resizeImage` with a width, height and resolution of your image.

```
resizemeth = ResampleMethod.BICUBIC;
res = 72;
w = 1000;
h = 673;
app.activeDocument.resizeImage(w, h, res, resizemeth);
```

Also check what *units* you are using.

alert(app.preferences.rulerUnits);